# "Rich with" vs "Rich in"

Tags: difference

> The salmon tastes awful, but it is ***rich with*** protein, omega-3 fatty
>   acids, and vitamin.

or

> The salmon tastes awful, but it is ***rich in*** protein, omega-3 fatty
>   acids, and vitamin.

Which one (rich WITH or rich IN) is correct in this case?

Comment: Salmon tastes *awful*? Who said that? They must be crazy or they don't know how to cook it.

Comment: Either is OK.  "rich in" is more common. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rich%20with%20vitamins%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rich **in**... is the much more common option, as shown by this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rich%20in%2C%20rich%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crich%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crich%20with%3B%2Cc0): there are not many **rich with**s, and many of them seem to be book-titles like "Get Rich with Dividends".